# finding the length of a numpy array

Tags: python, numpy

I am trying to find the length of a numpy array. But when i use the len() function it is giving an error like "TypeError: len() of unsized object"
also when i used the ".size" method the value i am getting is '1'.

my code is as follows

`for dt in daterange(start_dt, end_dt):
        dateComplete=np.array((dt.strftime("%Y-%m-%d")))
        print(dateComplete)
        x=len(dateComplete)
        print(x)`

i am trying to create an array contains all the dates between 1st january and today.

Comment: Your array `dateComplete` is a "scalar array"; it has shape `()`.  Such arrays act like scalars, not sequences, so `len` is not defined for them.  `len(a)` for a numpy array is, in effect, `a.shape[0]`.

Comment: `dateComplete` is a single element array like `array('2017-10-31', dtype='<U10')`.  Its element is a string.

Answer (score 0):

What exactly are you trying to achieve with your loop? If you want to have an array of dates and check its length, there's no need to iterate through it. I don't know what type of object `daterange` returns, but if its a numpy array (like with `pandas.date_range()`, you can get your desired array using the `.astype()` method:

```
dates = date_range(start_dt, end_dt).astype(str)
len(dates)
```

If it's a Python list, you can use list comprehension:

```
dates = [str(date) for date in date_range(start_dt, end_dt)]
len(dates)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use `dateComplete.shape`, it will return a tupple with the array's dimensions. See: https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.shape.html